# Two fixed divs - right and left

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, fixed

I would like to create two fixed divs on my webpage. First should be on the left, second on the right. I create some code but It doesn't work perfect.

Demo [here](http://zsws.tk)

I have no idea how to correct it. Any solutions?

Comment: It appears to me that you actually need 3 divs. One to the left, one to the right, and one on the middle to hold the text content.

Comment: The jquery code on your demo page is set to work the way the page is behaving. Did you write the code yourself or you want to adapt it to your needs?

Comment: there is no need to jQuery for doing this.

Comment: @undefined Do you mean "Vanilla JavaScript will work just fine", or are you trying to say this can be done without JS at all?

Comment: @JamWaffles I meant this can be done without JS, CSS can handle it well.

Comment: @undefined No it can't; CSS doesn't know when the page is scrolled, or when an element hits the top of the window. Do you mean JS isn't needed to center the content column on scroll?

Comment: actually CSS knows when `position: fixed` is used. however I can't see `scroll` in the question.

Comment: @undefined in the linked example the divs only start scrolling when they hit the top of the page - but you are correct, this has not been mentioned in the actual question

Comment: Since the user is new, and clearly is not expressing the problem properly, shouldn't the question be improved instead of arguing about it muddling the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page scrolls, you're setting a `position:fixed` to your `#aside` and `#bside` elements, by applying a class `fixed` and `fixed2`.

Since the `position:fixed` when aplied to `#aside` and `#bside`, takes them out of the document flow, the element `#main` is floating as expected to the left.

To avoid changing your current code, a simple solution would be to use a class to set certain styles to your `#main` element, and have that class applied as needed:

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/NV24K/) Example.

**CSS**

```
.fixMiddle {
    position: relative;
    left: 190px;         /* your #aside width+padding+border */
}
```

**jQuery**

```
if ($('#aside').hasClass('fixed')) {
  $('#main').addClass('fixMiddle');
} else {
  $('#main').removeClass('fixMiddle');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By providing a `margin` to **#main** that is equal to the width of the fixed columns, it'll keep that area from snapping back towards the left. When you apply `position:fixed` to the columns, it is taking those elements out of the flow of the document.

Since `position:fixed` is applied to the columns dynamically (through the use of JS), you may also consider applying the `margin` to **#main** dynamically as well, if for timing purposes only.